# Inkscape - how to draw a line with an arrow (as marker) in the middle with correct orientation

Tags: vector, inkscape, arrow

I would like to draw a light ray which makes an angle with the horizontal axis in Inkscape. Using the freehand drawing, I drew the line horizontally first (placing a node in the middle for the arrow) and then rotated the whole thing to the desired angle. However, I failed to rotate the marker arrow correctly (as seen in the figure below). I want it to have the same orientation as the line itself. How can I do that?

As a note: I'm sure that the line and the arrow are grouped together.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate the problem. If I draw a horizontal line, with a middle anchor point, then apply an arrow head, and then rotate the line, it works as expected. [See example here](https://imgur.com/tU628Ni)

Comment: Thanks for the example. After watching your video I opened a new file and tried the same thing and it worked. I realized that I was using a duplicate of an already-drawn horizontal ray for simplicity and obtained my angled-rays in the picture by rotating it. I don't know why that doesn't work but this seems to be the reason. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Copying or duplicating the line doesn't make any difference when I try it. [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/RwH1NW7).

Comment: See this question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/inkscape-arrow-skew

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thank you, that link helped a lot, "optimized" box was checked in my "Store transformations" option and when I changed it to "preserved" everything was OK. BillyKerr, thanks again for spending your time to record and upload the example video.

Comment: @sahin Hmmm . . .  in my settings "Store transformations" was set to "optimized" when I made these screen shots. So, that can't really be the source of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @BillyKerr this is really weird because that solved my problem. Maybe it's because of the versions we are using; mine is 0.92.4. This is the first time I'm using Inkscape by the way so it's also highly probable that I accidentally changed some other properties in the file I was working on.

Comment: Well, I was using 0.92.3, so I downloaded 0.92.4 just to make sure, and I still can't replicate the problem with Store transformations set to "optimised". [see example here](https://imgur.com/i46iZIk). Perhaps you are right, you might have changed something.  Are you sure you are doing a rotate transform and not a skew?

Comment: I can only reproduce a similar problem when I group the line first, then try to skew it, although it's hardly a problem, since it's what would be expected when skewing a group.

Comment: The file I was working on initially was like a scratch paper for me in which I was repeating some video tutorials. I don't exactly remember what I changed on the file during the tutorials but I'm sure that I didn't use the skewing property for the rays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a separate triangle or arrowhead on a plain line, make a group, rotate to the wanted direction. If needed, you can allways ungroup and even without ungrouping you can select the parts separately in the layers panel for ex. to stretch the line.

[image]